# XML Unmarshalling using JAXB from JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, jaxb

I have a JavRDD with complex nested xml content that I want to unmarshall using JAXB and get the data in rows and columns structure. How can I achieve?

Comment: Might this project be relevant? https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Comment: @Gelerion, I tried that but its not a fit for my use case. I have a deep nested xml, that  I need to loop in and flatten into multiple records.